# My std::exchange is not in namespace std?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, std

I included `<utility>` in my source file. Then I used `std::exchange`, but the compiler said it didn't found `exchange` in the namespace std. I looked at `usr/include/utility`, and by searching `exchange` I found the implementation, and it's inside the `namespace std` block. I had to remove `std::` from `std::exchange` to make the code compile.

Can I solve this?

How can I make my code portable otherwise?

Note: I am using clang from the Termux linux emulator on Android. I got clang by installing it with `apt`.

Comment: Did you enable `c++14`? `clang -std=c++14`?

Comment: @Holt I am using c++11... I'll try changing that. As I said, without `std::` it works though.

Comment: According to [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange), `std::exchange` is a C++14 function. Might just be pure coincidence that clang define it prior to that.

Comment: @Holt ok, c++14 solved this. Thabk you.

Answer (score 5):

`std::exchange` was introduced in C++14. If you use C++11, then it is not provided by the standard.

Solution: Use a C++14 compliant implementation (which may require enabling the support explicitly, depending on whether it is default or not).

> How can I make my code portable otherwise?

You can implement it yourself. Here is a possible implementation from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange).

> ```
> template<class T, class U = T>
> T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value)
> {
>     T old_value = std::move(obj);
>     obj = std::forward<U>(new_value);
>     return old_value;
> }
> ```